# Allegro .brd to Altium PCB conversion

Tags: altium, allegro

I have a PCB file that is in .brd (Allegro) format. I gave that to a manufacturer who was not able to open because he uses Altium and asked me to convert the file. Is this possible? I have looked on the internet but all the descriptions are too complex to understand. Can somebody provide a step-by-step solution to convert the .brd file to Altium PCB file? I have Altium installed in my machine.

Comment: If you have Allegro available, you should be able to generate Gerber and drill files which any PCB shop should be able to use.  I've never sent the board design file to a PCB shop.

Answer (score 1):

File->Import Wizard should do it, but I've never tried it with Allegro. It says it will import .brd files.

[image]

As per @TimWilliams comment below, the following is in [Altium's documentation](https://www.altium.com/documentation/knowledge-base/altium-designer/import-allegro-files-to-altium):

> In addition to this knowledge article, please review this documentation:
> https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/allegro-import

> Altium Designer supports the import of Allegro's native binary (*.brd)
> and ASCII (*.alg) files from Allegro (up to version 17.2). To import
> the files, Altium Designer ultimately needs the ASCII versions. Binary
> versions need to go through a conversion process that  requires a
> local installation of extracta.exe that is installed as part of
> Allegro to convert the *.brd file to the Allegro ASCII *.alg file that
> Altium needs for the import.  As this utility is part of the Allegro
> tools, Altium is unable to redistribute this file, or the DLLs
> required to run it.  Therefore, the conversion requires a machine with
> Allegro installed.  If that is not available, you can inquire with one
> of our service bureau members. Here's a link:
> https://altium.secure.force.com/servicebureaus Try using Allegro as a
> search word to reduce the list size, then double check that Services
> provided includes Allegro.

Comment: I believe it needs to be pre-converted, to some kind of ASCII or otherwise less-proprietary format, first.